# redirect_to not populating flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two methods:

```
def set_asset
    @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id])

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to assets_url, notice: 'resource does not exist'
end

def get
    send_file @asset.uploaded_file.path, type: @asset.uploaded_file_content_type

    rescue ActionController::MissingFile
        redirect_to assets_url, notice: 'missing file'
end
```

In the event of a MissingFile or RecordNotFound being raised, the rescue blocks in these methods successfully redirect to the assets_url path. However, the flash is not set (I've debugged it)!

Why could this be happening. I've tried flash.now[:notice] = and that doesn't work either (even though that should only be used when rendering a different view)...

**Update**

Right now, this is all my assets/index.html.haml view contains:

```
= debug flash
```

And it's constantly empty

Comment: Can you add the views in which the flash doesn't seem to be displaying, i.e. your `assets_url` view?

Comment: Do not ever. NEVER. rescue exceptions. If you know something is gonna fail, prevent it, never rescue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller.rb

```
flash[:notice] = "resource does not exist"
```

View

```
-flash.each do |name, msg|
  = label_tag msg
```